# Query.CompositeFilter generates java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datastore

Did anyone experience this yet?

I was using *Query.addFilter(...)* and it worked/works fine. 
If I change to use ***Query.CompositeFilter*** instead, I'm hitting the **java.lang.VerifyError**  during runtime as soon as I use the file that uses *Query.CompositeFilter*.

Am I missing something here? I'm using JDK 6.

Comment: Can you post the code please?